# Confirmation of terminology: Solvable ideal in a Lie algebra

Tags: ideals, lie-algebras

I am (slowly, but steadily) reading J-P. Serre's book on semisimple Lie algebras. The term "solvable ideal" (in a Lie algebra) has been introduced.

I'm interpretting this to mean that if I is a solvable ideal, I just consider it solvable as a Lie subalgebra, in the sense that I usually know Lie algebras to be solvable.

This makes sense, I'm just slightly wary as other terms which have been introduced didn't quite have the initial meaning I presumed them to have. Can anyone confirm that the above is definitely what we mean by solvable ideal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. That's what “solvable ideal” means.